# Haskell recursion in 'do' notation

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm reading this tutorial http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads and stumbled upon this definition:

```
type KnightPos = (Int,Int) 

moveKnight :: KnightPos -> [KnightPos]  
moveKnight (c,r) = do  
    (c',r') <- [(c+2,r-1),(c+2,r+1),(c-2,r-1),(c-2,r+1)  
               ,(c+1,r-2),(c+1,r+2),(c-1,r-2),(c-1,r+2)  
               ]  
    guard (c' `elem` [1..8] && r' `elem` [1..8])  
    return (c',r') 

in3 :: KnightPos -> [KnightPos]  
in3 start = do   
    first <- moveKnight start  
    second <- moveKnight first  
    moveKnight second
```

I have a question regarding function `in3` (which takes a pair of coordinates (Int,Int) on a chessboard and produces a list of fields [(Int,Int)] reachable from that field in exactly 3 moves of a knight).
Is it possible (and if so - how to do it) to remake that function into 
`inNMoves :: (Num a) => KnightPos -> a -> [KnightPos]` 
so that it also takes the number of moves as an argument, instead of being bound to exactly 3 jumps?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As this exercise is about the List *Monad*, try to not think of what you know about lists, but limit yourself to the structure of monads. So that would be

```
move :: Monad m => Pos -> m Pos
```

That is, `move` takes a `Pos` and gives you back something that is about `Pos` things in some monadic context `m`. (In the case of lists, the "context" being "arbitrary multiplicity + ordering". But try not to think about it).

Also, let's not talk about `do` here which is only syntactic sugar for using `(>>=)`. For the purposes of this explanation, you are required to know how do translates to expressions using `(>>=)`.

`(>>=)` has signature `m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. The instance which we need being `m Pos -> (Pos -> m Pos) -> m Pos`. You see we have instanciated both `a` and `b` here to `Pos`. You also can recognize the middle part `(Pos -> m Pos)` being `move`'s signature here. So using `(>>=)` and giving it `move` as second argument, we can make a function of type `m Pos -> m Pos`.

```
moveM :: Monad m => m Pos -> m Pos
moveM mp = mp >>= move
```

**Composition of monad endomorphisms**

It is clear that `m Pos -> m Pos` can be executed in sequence as often as you wish since it is a function from a type to itself (I think that can be called *monad endomorphism* since the type is a monad).

Let's write a function which does two moves.

```
move2M :: Monad m => m Pos -> m Pos
move2M mp = moveM (moveM (mp))
```

Or in pointfree style (thinking only about the *transformation*, not about the transformated object):

```
move2M :: Monad m => m Pos -> m Pos
move2M = moveM . moveM
```

For the general case (number of moves parameterized by an integer `n`) we just want some number of `moveM`s connected by the function chaining operator `.`. So if n is 3, we want `moveM . moveM . moveM`. Here's how to do this programmatically:

```
nmoveM :: Monad m => Int -> m Pos -> m Pos
nmoveM n = foldr1 (.) (replicate n moveM)  -- n "moveM"s connected by (.)
```

A question arises here: What is the result of moving 0 times? `foldr1` is undefined for values of `n` <= 0. It makes quite a lot of sense to define `nmoveM 0` to "doing nothing". In other words, the identity function, `id`.

```
nmoveM :: Monad m => Int -> m Pos -> m Pos
nmoveM n = foldr (.) id (replicate n moveM)
```

Here, we used `foldr` instead of `foldr1` which needs an additional "base case", `id`.

Now we basically have what we want, but the type signature doesn't fit 100%: We have a `m Pos -> m Pos`, but we want `Pos -> m Pos`. That means, given a `Pos`, we first have to embed it in the context `m`, and then execute `nMoveM`. This embedding operator (i think it could be called *initial algebra*) is `return` (of type `Monad m => a -> m a`)

```
nmoves :: Monad m => Int -> Pos -> m Pos
nmoves n = nmoveM n . return
```

Let's write all that at once so you can appreciate the terseness in its full glory.

```
nmoves :: Monad m => Int -> Pos -> m Pos
nmoves n = foldr (.) id (replicate n move) . return
```

**Composition of arrows**

Using `(>>=)` is actually often a little unclean because it is so un-symmetric: It takes an `m a` and an `a -> m b`. In other words, it is a little too concerned about the transformed object, instead only the transformation for our case. This makes it unnecessarily hard to compose transformations. That's why we had to tack on `. return`: It's the initial transformation from `Pos` to `m Pos`, so that we can freely combine arbitrary amounts of `m Pos -> m Pos`.

Using `(>>=)` results in the following pattern:

```
ma >>= f_1 >>= f_2 >>= ... >>= f_n
```

where `ma` is a monad thing and the `f_i` are "arrows" of type `a -> m b` (where often a = b).

There is a much nicer variant, `(>=>)`, which combines two `a -> m b` type arrows in a sequence, and returns another arrow.

```
(>=>) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> (a -> m c)
```

Here we are not unnecessarily concerned with the transformed objects, but only with transformations and their composition.

Now let's agree that `move` is actually such an arrow (`Pos -> m Pos`). So

```
move >=> move >=> move >=> move >=> move
```

is a valid expression still of type `Pos -> m Pos`. The composable nature of monads becomes much more apparent when using `(>=>)`.

We could re-write `nmoves` using `(>=>)` like so:

```
nmoves :: Monad m => Int -> Pos -> m Pos
nmoves n = foldr1 (>=>) (replicate n move)  -- n "move"s connected by >=>
```

Again, we used `foldr1`, and we are asking "what gives 0 times move in a row"? It must be of the same type, `Pos -> m Pos`, and the answer is `return`.

```
nmoves :: Monad m => Int -> Pos -> m Pos
nmoves n = foldr (>=>) return (replicate n move)
```

Compare this to our earlier definition of `nmoves` in the monad endomorphisms world: Instead of functions combined with `(.)` and the base case `id`, we now combine arrows with `(>=>)` and the base case `return`. The benefit being that we don't have to inject the given `Pos` to `m Pos`.

What makes more sense depends on your case, but more often than not `(>=>)` is much cleaner than `(>>=)`.

Answer (score 4):

Using direct recursion:

```
inNMoves :: KnightPos -> Int -> [KnightPos]
inNMoves start 0 = return start
inNMoves start n = do
  first <- moveKnight start
  inNMoves first (n - 1)
```

But as mentioned in the comments: you can use built-in functions for this. For example:

```
inNMoves start n = (foldl (>>=) . return) start (replicate n moveKnight)
```

Or even completely pointfree:

```
inNMoves = (. flip replicate moveKnight) . foldl (>>=) . return
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that `concatMap moveKnight` has type `[Knight] -> [Knight]` and will return the positions reachable from the input positions.

Knowing that, you can use:

```
iterate (concatMap moveKnight)
```

to generate an infinite list of sets of positions where the next set of positions is obtained by making a knight move from a position in the previous set.

For example:

```
iterate (concatMap moveKnight) [(1,2)]
  = [ [(1,2)],               -- the initial list
      [(3,1),(3,3),(2,4)],   -- after one iteration
      [(5,2),(1,2),(4,3),(2,3), ... -- after two iterations
      ...
    ]
```

Now `in3` may be written as

```
in3 xs = moves !! 3
  where moves = iterate (concatMap moveKnight) xs
```

Comment: That's a nice explanation but I think it would be more appropriate to give a monad explanation.